# Fastest way to update rows of an array of SparseArrays

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I have an array of sparse arrays (check update 3 below for a concrete example that has the same qualitative features as what I use in my real code) , say

```
sparse = Table[
  KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 50}], 
   IdentityMatrix[50, SparseArray]], {ii, 1, 5}, {jj, 1, 5}];
```

and I want to do 2 things:

1) Set the non-zero elements in every nth row (except for the last n+1 rows) in each sparse array to 0.

I currently do this by

```
n=3;
AbsoluteTiming[
 sparse[[All, All, 1 ;; -n-1 ;; n]] = 
   ConstantArray[0., Dimensions[sparse[[All, All, 1 ;; -n-1 ;; n]]]];]

{0.38174, Null}
```

and

2) update some of the rows of some of the sparse arrays (not all of them) with the rows from other arrays (that I generate separately)

for example

```
randMatrix1 = 
  KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 50}], 
   IdentityMatrix[50, SparseArray]];
randMatrix2 = 
  KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50, 50}], 
   IdentityMatrix[50, SparseArray]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 sparse[[1, 1]][[1 ;; -n - 1 ;; n + 1]] = 
  randMatrix1[[1 ;; -n - 1 ;; n + 1]];
 sparse[[2, 3]][[n + 1 ;; -1 ;; n + 1]] = 
  randMatrix2[[n + 1 ;; -1 ;; n + 1]];]

{0.001794, Null}
```

Ok, the last one is quite quick, but I have to do it many times, as I have different combinations of rows that should be replaced with rows from different matrices. Also in my real code the sizes are larger and `randMatrix1` and `randMatrix2` can be either sparse or dense.

How can these operations by sped up, or is there a completely different way of doing this?

**UPDATE:** Added the information that `randMatrix1` and `randMatrix2` can be either sparse or dense.

**UPDATE 2:** There is also the special case when `randMatrix1` and `randMatrix2` are the `IdentitiyMatrix`. Is that case any easier for some reason?

**UPDATE 3:** Per request in some of the answers, I provide code that produces an array of matrices similar to what I work with in my real problem

```
{dm1, dm2, dm3, dm4, dm5} = 
  Table[SparseArray[
    Flatten[Table[
       RandomReal[{0, 1}, 250][[ii]]*
        Block[{vec}, vec = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10}]; 
         vec - Min[Abs[vec]]], {ii, 1, 250}]]*
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2500, 2500}]], 5];

sm = Table[
   SparseArray[
    Block[{vec}, vec = ConstantArray[0., 2500]; 
      vec[[3]] = RandomReal[{0., 10.}]; vec]*
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2500, 2500}]], 20];

sA = {{dm1, sm[[1]], sm[[2]], sm[[3]], sm[[4]]}, {sm[[5]], dm2, 
    sm[[6]], sm[[7]], sm[[8]]}, {sm[[9]], sm[[10]], dm3, sm[[11]], 
    sm[[12]]}, {sm[[13]], sm[[14]], sm[[15]], dm4, 
    sm[[16]]}, {sm[[17]], sm[[18]], sm[[19]], sm[[20]], dm5}};
```

Where `sA` is basically what I am working with in my real problem (apart from dimensions, of course, but that should be large enough). So the diagonal terms are very dense, whereas everything else is very sparse.

I am not sure I can `ArrayFlatten` the whole thing and then do the changes I want, as the changes to each block matrix are different (in the sense that the same rows get updated, but with different values) and implementing them in one go for all the blocks will be very hard, or at least my knowledge of `Mathematica` doesn't let me see how this can be done.

**UPDATE 4: Partial solution**
So I think the problem is that the diagonal sparse arrays in my list of sparse arrays are very dense. Hence if I actually normalise them and then do the replacements things speed up. Here is how I do it

```
dim = 49; n = 49;
replace = Normal /@ Diagonal[sA];
(sA[[#, #]] = replace[[#]]) & /@ Range[5];
sA[[All, All, 1 ;; -n - 1 ;; n + 1]] *= 0.;(*and other replacements*)
replace = SparseArray /@ Diagonal[sA];
(sA[[#, #]] = replace[[#]]) & /@ Range[5];
```

and then I can `ArrayFlatten` the whole thing and continue with my calculation. Not very elegant but it helps a bit.

Comment: If someone edits this I’d like to upvote it! Sometimes I accidentally downvote questions that I actually like (like this one!) no clue how it happens. Thanks for asking a good question!

Comment: @CATrevillian what do you mean by 'someone edits it'?

Comment: Just that I can’t change my vote until there is a useful/accepted edit provided.

Comment: @CATrevillian I made an edit

Answer (score 8):

The following did the first trick 40 times faster (on my machine):

```
sparse[[All, All, 1 ;; -n - 1 ;; n]] *= 0.
```

One of the major problems here is that

```
ConstantArray[0., Dimensions[b[[All, All, 1 ;; -n - 1 ;; n]]]]
```

is a dense array although it conveys basically no information.

Comment: I can't test it now, as I am traveling. However, I forgot to mention that in 2) `randMatrix1` and `randMatrix2` can be either dense or sparse. I updated the question with that information

Comment: I tested the code and in this way it is way faster but applying it to my real code yields about the same times. The reason is that the structure of my array of sparse arrays is very specific (they all come after a lot of operations, starting with very sparse arrays). The diagonal ones are very dense, but all the rest are almost empty. In the end I 'ArrayFlatten' the whole thing and it is sparse as a whole. Shall I update my question with more details or I can provide a '{5,5,2601,2601}' examplary array if I am allowed to upload files here.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi Maybe you can provide the _code_ that would produce a typical example of your array. Moreover this: In contrast to in-place operations on dense matrices, "in-place operations" on sparse arrays have typically to rebuild the whole matrix structure if the sparsity pattern changes. So it might also make sense to `ArrayFlatten` the whole array and to perform the according row operations on the resulting sparse array. This might reduce overhead time (for rebuilding the sparsity pattern(s)).

Comment: If the sparsity pattern does not change, then one should also try to modify only the vector of `"NonzeroValues"`; that would be super fast. But from what you said, the sparsity pattern does change, right?

Comment: I updated my post as per your request. I was inactive as I have been travelling across continents for work.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Henrik solution:

Generate data:

```
dim = 50;
sparse = Table[
   KroneckerProduct[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {dim, dim}], 
    IdentityMatrix[dim, SparseArray]], {ii, 1, 5}, {jj, 1, 5}];
```

My method:

```
n = 3;
AbsoluteTiming[
 sp = SparseArray[
   Drop[ArrayRules[IdentityMatrix[dim^2, SparseArray]], {1, -n, 
     n}], {dim^2, dim^2}];
 sparse1 = sp.# & /@ # & /@ sparse;
 ]
```

> {0.170991, Null}

Henrik's method:

```
sparse2 = sparse;
n = 3;
AbsoluteTiming[
 sparse2[[All, All, 1 ;; -n - 1 ;; n]] *= 0.;
 ]
```

> {0.092583, Null}

```
sparse1==sparse2
```

> True

Unfortunately, my method takes twice the time of Henrik's one (tested with different dim values), and is much more verbose, but I think is an interesting comparison!

Comment: I tested this exact implementation on my real code (which doesn't work that well with Henrik's solution) and it is slower than both my implementation and Henrik's, but this is due to the specifics of my real problem (see comment under Henrik's post)