# Replace the diagonal of a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I want to replace the diagonal of a square list of matrices with another list of matrices. What is the fastest and most efficient way to do so. (I will need to do this for very large arrays)

Small example below

```
m1 = {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{9, 10}, {11, 
      12}}, {{13, 14}, {15, 16}}}};

v1 = {{{11, 3}, {7, 5}}, {{13, 97}, {3, 16}}};

m1[[1, 1]] = v1[[1]]; m1[[2, 2]] = v1[[2]];


m1

{{{{11, 3}, {7, 5}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{9, 10}, {11, 
    12}}, {{13, 97}, {3, 16}}}}
```

Comment: One way is to use `ReplacePart`, e.g. `ReplacePart[m1, {i_,i_} :> v1[[i]]]` - not sure about efficiency tough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's generate sample data:

```
array = ConstantArray[
   RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {100, 100}], {100, 100}];
replace = ConstantArray[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {100, 100}], 100];

array1 = array2 = array3 = array4 = array;
```

and apply different methods:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Table[array1[[i, i]] = replace[[i]], {i, Length@replace}];]
```

> {0.0064, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[(array2[[#, #]] = replace[[#]]) & /@ 
   Range[Length@replace];]
```

> {0.0071, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[array3=ReplacePart[array3, {i_, i_} :> replace[[i]]];]
```

> {12.9, Null}

```
RepeatedTiming[
 ParallelTable[array4[[i, i]] = replace[[i]], {i, Length@replace}];]
```

> {0.016, Null}

```
array1 == array2 == array3 == array4
```

> True

Suggested by Alx (the fastest so far):

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Do[array1[[i, i]] = replace[[i]], {i, Length@replace}];]
```

> {0.0018, Null}

Comment: I love the second option! Thank you!

Comment: On my system `Do` instead of `Table` in the first method is 2--3 times faster.

Comment: @Alx same on my machine, thx! I'll add it on my list.

Answer (score 4):

We can also use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)s.

```
m1 = {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{9, 10}, {11, 12}}, {{13, 14}, {15, 16}}}};
v1 = {{{11, 3}, {7, 5}}, {{13, 97}, {3, 16}}};
res = {{{{11, 3}, {7, 5}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}, {{{9, 10}, {11, 12}}, {{13, 97}, {3, 16}}}};

blockmatrixreplace[mat_, rep_] := Block[
 {
  diagonalmatrixindices = Flatten[Table[{i, i, j, k}, ##] & @@ ({#, Dimensions[mat][[1]]} & /@ {i, j, k}), 2],
  emptydiag,
  repten
 },
 emptydiag = SparseArray[mat] - SparseArray[diagonalmatrixindices -> Flatten@Diagonal@mat, Dimensions[mat]];
 repten = SparseArray[diagonalmatrixindices -> Flatten@rep, Dimensions[mat]];
 emptydiag + repten // Normal
]

{#1, #2 == res} & @@ RepeatedTiming@blockmatrixreplace[m1, v1]
```

> {0.000055, True}

Or we could use [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) in the `SparseArray` since

> With an array a of the same rank as the whole sparse array, Band[start]->a by default inserts a at the position specified by start.

```
bandblockmatrixreplace[mat_, rep_] := Block[
 {diagreps, offdiagreps, reps},
 diagreps = MapIndexed[Band[{#2[[1]], #2[[1]], 1, 1}] -> {{#1}} &, rep];
 offdiagreps = Table[Band[{j, k, 1, 1}] -> {{mat[[j, k]]}}, {j, #1}, {k, Range[#2]~Complement~{j}}] & @@ Dimensions[mat][[;; 2]] // Flatten;
 reps = Join[diagreps, offdiagreps];
 Normal@SparseArray[reps, Dimensions@mat]
]
{#1, #2 == res} & @@ RepeatedTiming@bandblockmatrixreplace[m1, v1]
```

> {0.000070, True}

Comment: This indeed answers my question exactly. However, in my real code mat is actually an array of sparse arrays, where the diagonal ones are very dense, but the off-diagonal ones are very sparse (so once array-flattened the whole thing is sparse, like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208296/fastest-way-to-update-rows-of-an-array-of-sparsearrays)). So I can't really make them work with my real setup. I think for the 1st suggestion the list of rules doesn't work and in general taking `SparseArray[mat]` takes a lot of time